# handling peer (or nested?) dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, package.json

For the very first time, I encountered a scenario where I need to (I think) handle peer dependencies in a package I am using.

I was bumping dependencies of my app, and this is my scenario:

1. I use package A as dependency
2. Package A has package B as peer dependency and uses also package C
3. Package C uses package B as 'normal' dependency
4. I myself use package B as direct dependency

After updating package B in my project, package C complains about some breaking import from package B

I did my reading about this topic but honestly I don't quite understand how can I work around.

Should I upgrade package B in my app just to the point that does not break anything? (if that is even possible considering that my point is to update my dependencies, and some of them would require having B at X point)

Should I try to update dependencies on package A (where B exist as peer dependency, and uses also C, which is the one complaining?)

What options do I have?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's best to avoid having a package be both a direct dependency and a peer dependency of the same application. In this case, you have several options for resolving the issue:

- If possible, try to upgrade package B in your app to the latest version that does not break anything. This will ensure that all of your dependencies are using the same version of package B, which should prevent any conflicts.
- If you're unable to upgrade package B without breaking something, you can try to update the dependencies of package A. This may involve updating package C to a version that is compatible with the version of package B that you're using in your app.
- Alternatively, you could try to remove package B as a direct dependency of your app and only use it as a peer dependency of package A. This may involve updating your code to import package B from package A, rather than importing it directly.